# C# - Loop through HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am generating HTML text areas with javascript code below:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 1;
        $('#add').click(function () {
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><textarea runat="server" id="choice"  placeholder="Enter choice text" class="form-control"></textarea></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
        });

    });
```

After generating text areas, i want to get values of it. I have tried to get values with the code below:

```
   foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
    {
        ArrayList ary = new ArrayList();
        //We just need HtmlInputCheckBox 
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea _cbx = item as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea;
        if (_cbx != null)
        {


            ary.Add(_cbx.Attributes["id"].ToString());


        }

    }
```

But, it can not find any values. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can't do that, if you want to be able to manipulate the controls on the server side, then you must create them on the server side.

Comment: You can get the values server side only if they have a name attribute, and you use something like `Request.Form["element_name"]` to get the value.

Comment: My main problem is to let user add more textbox when creating a question with choices. Is there any efficient way that you can advice?.

Comment: Yes. Do what Sam just advised - create them with a "name" attribute and then you can reference them on the server.